# Android Studio: Gradle sync failed: Unable to load class

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Since i've reinstalled Android Studio i have a strange problem everytime i create a project. Immediately after creating it, i get the Exception :
Gradle sync failed: Unable to load class 'org.gradle.internal.typeconversion.NotationConverter'.
 and therefore i cant do anything at all in android studio at the moment.

I already tried all of the follwoing suggestions and i also cleaned and rebuild the project although that shouldnt be the problem because the problem also appears whenever im creating a new project.

> Error:Unable to load class 'org.gradle.internal.typeconversion.NotationConverter'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Someone on my team just ran in to this today. Somehow, their install of gradle became corrupted. Solution was to remove it – the gradle wrapper downloaded a replacement as soon as we invoked it again. So:

1. Find the version/package of gradle your project is using: look in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and observe the gradle version (e.g., `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip` is `gradle-6.5-bin`.)
2. Remove the corresponding gradle package from your gradle cache: e.g., `rm -r ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.5-bin`
3. Invoke the gradle wrapper again (on command line or from AS, doesn't matter), and it will download a new package to replace the one you removed: (e.g., `./gradlew assembleDebug`)

After that, we were "back in business!"